# WP_Query over two meta keys are sorted separately

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've stumbled upon a WordPress query problem I don't seem to be able to fix.

I've got a custom post type called *products* that has two fields, `price` and `price_campaign`. Sometimes, `price` is only set, sometimes it's only `price_campaign`. I still want my final query to output all products in order, ordered by `price`/`price_campaign`, as if these two fields were the same. I don't seem to be able to do that, though:

```
$query->set(
    'meta_query',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'price_campaign' => array(
            'key' => 'price_campaign',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        'price' => array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    )
);

$query->set(
    'orderby',
    array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
        'title' => 'ASC'
    )
);
```

But what happens is that I first get the products that has `price` set and then all the ones with `price_campaign` set.
If I change it to `'relation' => 'OR'` they are just put out in a completely random order, where neither prices nor titles seem to matter.

I really can't figure out what's the problem. Any ideas?